# How to access grand-child's variable in a closure

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I want to retrieve the values of a and b from p in the code given below. I would also like to run the function z from p. How do I achieve this?

```
function x() {
    var a = 10;
    return function y() {
        var b = 20;
        return function z() {
            console.log(a, b);
        }
    }
}
const p = x();
```

I'm new to JS.

Comment: To run `z()` you can write `p()`, or `x()()` which is equivalent. There's no way to obtain `a` and `b` values unless you return them

Comment: I failed to see the structure, it's actually `p()()` or `x()()()`, because `x` is a function that returns a function that returns a function

Comment: @Christian Vincenzo Traina p() just prints the function z in words, not the values of a and b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function x() {
    var a = 10;
    return function y() {
        var b = 20;
        return function z() {
            console.log(a,b)
        }
    }
}
// get function z
const result = x()();
console.log(result)
// get a,b 
result()
```

Calling x returns function y, calling y returns function z ***i.e. x()();***

 By calling function z, you can get a,b (return or console) ***i.e. x()()();***